# Update Textboxes with Contacts Details from listboxes

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a program to update  a Listbox with a list of contacts. Created a contact Class without problems.

I am facing problems in displaying the details of the currently selected contact in the textboxes.

Also I can't add an item until the Listbox has at least has one item present.

Here is the ShowContacts subroutine:

```
 Dim adding As Boolean
        Dim currentContact As Integer 'holds position of current contact
            Private Sub ShowContact()
                    Dim contact As New Contact()
            contact=contactsListBox.Items(currentcontact) 'Problems here 
                    txtAddress.Text = contact.Address
                    txtCity.Text = contact.City
                    txtCompany.Text = contact.CompanyName
                    txtContact.Text = contact.ContactName
                    txtMobile.Text = contact.Mobile
                    txtState.Text = contact.State
                    txtzip.Text = contact.Zip
                End Sub


         '  And this to Save Contacts:
             Private Sub SaveContact()
                    Dim contact As New Contact()
                    contact.CompanyName = txtCompany.Text
                    contact.Address = txtAddress.Text
                    contact.City = txtCity.Text
                    contact.ContactName = txtContact.Text
                    contact.Email = txtEmail.Text
                    contact.Mobile = txtMobile.Text
                    contact.State = txtState.Text
                    contact.Zip = txtState.Text
                    If contactsListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                        If adding Then
                            contactsListBox.Items.Add(contact).ToString()
                        Else
                            contactsListBox.Items(currentContact) = contact
                            contactsListBox.Items.RemoveAt(currentContact)
                            contactsListBox.Items.Add(contact).ToString()
                        End If
                    End If
                End Sub
```

Comment: so you want the contact to show of what the listbox is selecting?

Comment: Yes the corresponding contacts details should be displayed in the textboxes.

Comment: there are a few ways you would go about it, 1 would be the IF Statement, and another that could possibly work would be the CASE Statement, find what works best for your app.

Comment: How do i ask the ShowContact() sub to update the textboxes with the details of selected contacts

Comment: something like this? `TextBox1.Update()`

Comment: How will the sub know which contact is being referred to because there is a runtime error

Comment: Try using the Dictionary.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

Comment: each name of the person could be the Tkey, and the details about that person could be the TValue. you could tell the program once pressing the save, to add the details from the textboxes to the TValue. Good Luck!

Comment: And What about Show()

Comment: the listbox will contain your Tkeys, i could hold your hand, i have told you want you need to know, it is now up to you, of course there are many ways to complete this task, however from what i can understand i would use a dictionary, or even SQL....

Comment: Ok thanks for this is the first time i Have received proper responses to my question on SO.

Comment: no problem happy to help, but take my advice, use an SQL database, set it up within your project so an SQL Server isn't required.

Comment: Actually I got no experience with SQL and dictionaries but i will try to look up

Comment: Lucky for you i made a video explaining how to do so.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLs44hxV514

Comment: What should be the file type of my sql express download? Azure,iso or cab

Comment: follow the video link i sent you.

Comment: Didn't understand  the code quite but yes it worked so thanks

Comment: no problem at all, if you founds my answer helpful, please mark it as correct for the next person that comes across this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, i would use an SQL database.

Here is a video i made as a guide you can follow to help set your database up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8GQIfniA4c
If you have any problems, let me know and i'll do my best to help you out.
Happy Coding!